# regarding signin/signout, is authenticated in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on login/signup module(FYI no rolls/membership just a simple login form),data flow is from sql server for both registeration and login,and code is currently working fine.
I am trying to use signin/signout functionality in my code. I have already created a login form and the user is able to login and after successful login, user is redirected to default_page.aspx.
my r&d code upto this is as:

```
<td width="122" align="right"><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
            onclick="LinkButton1_Click">Sign Out</asp:LinkButton></td>
```

cs page:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //After click Log out we need to delete all session values


    Session.RemoveAll();
    Response.Redirect("userlogin.aspx");
}
```

from above code u can see I have put only a linkbutton and if user click on above link button user got sign out and redirected to loginpage(here userlogin.aspx). But now if I am trying to change(see below aspx and .cs) as signin|signout i am getting error as:**'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' does not contain a definition for 'IsAuthenticated' and no extension method 'IsAuthenticated' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

aspx page:

```
<td width="122" align="right"><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSignInOut" runat="server" 
            onclick="LinkButton1_Click">""</asp:LinkButton></td>
```

.cs page:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //After click Log out we need to delete all session values
    if (User.IsAuthenticated)**//error is here**
        LinkButtonSignInOut.Text = "Sign Out";
    else
        LabelSignInOut.Text = "Sign In"; 

    Session.RemoveAll();
    Response.Redirect("userlogin.aspx");
}
```

Any suggestions???

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code, I have wrote the comment

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.IsAuthenticated) **//error is here**
    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // this is correct code
         LinkButtonSignInOut.Text = "Sign Out";
    else
        LabelSignInOut.Text = "Sign In";

    Session.RemoveAll(); //
    Session.Abandon(); // Better to use this
    Response.Redirect("userlogin.aspx"); 
    // You are display assigning text in label and immediate after you are redirecting it to another page ??
}
```

Comment: @thanks...but currently not having windows to check your code...yeah you are right about wrong redirection...but currently i am working on this.